# Meromorphic functions on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ are rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

I was reading through a proof of the fact that all meromorphic functions on $\hat {\mathbb{C}}$ are rational functions found here

http://math.haifa.ac.il/hinich/RSlec/lec1.pdf

and I didn't understand the justification behind the statement

"The set of poles of a meromorphic function is discrete,
therefore, finite since $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is compact"

I understand that $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is compact, but I don't see how that gives us that the number of poles is finite.

for example, the analytic continuation of the gamma function has an infinite number of poles, and I thought that *was* meromorphic.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: To address your final point, the gamma function is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, but not on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$!

Comment: And that's because on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ all of the poles form a sort of "cluster point" at infinity so the singularity there isn't isolated? I guess I'm just not sure why a singularity at infinity wouldn't be isolated since it's a single point.

Comment: They don't form a "sort of" cluster point: they literally have a cluster point at $\infty$.  It may be helpful to consider the change of coordinates $w=1/z$, which sends $z=\infty$ to $w=0$.  In the $w$ coordinates, there are poles which accumulate at $0$, so there is a non-isolated singularity at $0$.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Thank you for your patience and for explaining this multiple times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are infinitely many poles, they have a limit point in $\widehat{\mathbb C}$.  In your example, that limit point is $\infty$.  The limit point is a singularity of the function, but not an isolated singularity, so the function is not meromorphic on $\widehat{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'm still a little confused as to why I can't have a function with a pole at every integer. Aren't the integers isolated? Or am I missing something about the extended complex plane?

Comment: @JonHales: The integers are isolated, but not closed: they accumulate at $\infty$.  So a function with a pole at every integer also has a singularity at $\infty$.